# Radian of 90 degrees is at 45

Tags: javascript, radians

Ok I have constructed a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/roLLqfs6/1/

Questions, why am I seeing all the lines overlapping and why even when I construct a radian from a degree is it still overlapping?

```
var radians = 90 * (Math.PI/180); //90 degrees if I'm not mistaken
```

also this chart shows radians ranging between 0 and 6.2, but in javascript i am seeing numbers for radians sometimes with minus in front. (example: -3.0924735724101273) what's up with that?

[image]

And this shows minus

[image]

which is correct (I suppose both are but I am finding my self confused as to what the range actually is)

Comment: Javascript's Math methods return radians between -Math.PI and +Math.PI. Interpret negative radians exactly like how negative degrees are interpreted in your second image. This works since the trigonometric functions are periodic.

Comment: ok but what is the +/- range?

Comment: before `c.lineTo` use `c.moveTo(0,0);`, (second `cos` to `sin`) I think this is the effect you try to get to. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ladvzxs4/)

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the JS code in your question (you may [edit] it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you should multiply with `Math.sin()` instead of `Math.cos()` for the Y-coordinate. See updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roLLqfs6/2/)

```
for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
    c.lineTo(
        100 + 100 * Math.cos(r[i]),
        100 + 100 * Math.sin(r[i])
    );
}
```

Comment: If not specified, the "starting point" for each line is where the last line finished, right?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you call Math.cos twice, for both moving on both the x and y axis. So you'll always be drawing a diagonal line. Change your second call to Math.sin:

```
for(var i=0;i<=r.length-1;i++){
    c.lineTo(
        100+(100)*Math.cos(r[i]),
        100+(100)*Math.sin(r[i])
    );}
```